# How do find rate of convergence in newton's method with multiple roots?

Tags: numerical-methods

I'm trying to solve the following problem.

[image]

I've proven the two equalities, but can't figure out how to prove that last bit about the rate of convergence being equal to $\log_{10}(2)$.

Comment: This is an alternative definition of "rate". It tells you how fast the amount of correct decimal digit grows per iteration.

Comment: @LutzLehmann Thank you, but how do I see that that is what the rate is?

Comment: Because $\frac1{2^k}=10^{-k·\log{10}(2)}$. If the error is smaller than $10^{-d}$, then in a majority of cases the first $d$ decimal digits after the dot are fixed.